# How specify type of class (not its instance) in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have classes:

```
class Model { 
  static get schema() { }   // static property 'schema'
}
class CustomModel_1 extends Model { }
. . .
class CustomModel_N extends Model { }
```

I want to declare a new function with argument that specified a type of model (not instance of this type):

```
/**
* @param {Model} ModelType  <== it is a wrong type because it is an instance of Model
*/
function doSomething(ModelType) {
  const schema = ModelType.schema // <== WebStorm emphasizes 'schema'
}
```

How I can specify it in JSDoc? Expression `{Model}` is invalid because it specifies the instance of Model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may wish to try this:

```
/**
 * @param {Model.constructor} ModelType
 */
function doSomething(ModelType) {
  // ...
}
```

That is, you can refer to the constructor function of an object (essentially the class) through its `constructor` property, which is a built-in property of any JavaScript object.

Depending on your environment, you may also want to try the following:

```
/**
 * @param {typeof Model} ModelType
 */
```

This type expression is supported by the [Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) used by JSDoc, although personally I didn't use this since part of my toolchain didn't support this particular syntax.

Also see this [JSDoc Typeof Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-typeof-plugin), which was the solution that finally worked for me in VSCode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, WebStorm does not support these two solutions.

Comment: Eventually I was able to satisfy VSCode (and its Intellisense Typescript Checker), and jsdoc, using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-typeof-plugin which converts the {typeof Foo} syntax to {Class<Foo>} just as it is passed to JSDoc.

Answer (score 1):

This currently works out of the box to aid Visual Studio Code (VScode) with Intellisense auto-completions:

```
/**
 * @param {typeof Model} ModelType
 */
```

it just works without any further configuration.

@Darren's answer above is somewhat misleading, it says that `jsdoc-typeof-plugin` "was the solution that finally worked for me in VSCode", but one doesn't need that plugin on VSCode at all.